# How I can read multiple web addresses with "%" sign in address that block dynamic iteration with sprintf?

Tags: r, web-scraping

Code I used to scrape website with multiple pages uses sprintf function that iterate by changing url's dynamic part "%d" for pages. But recently website I scrape added into address some variables which has "%". So further I cannot scrape because it gives error mapping function I use with sprintf for these newly added % sign?

```
url_base <- "https://www.xxxxxx.com/girne?s-r=S&property_type=1&property=&min_price=&max_price=&currency=1&min_m2=&max_m2=&title-type%5B0%5D=1&page=%d&sort=mr"
map_df(1:10,function(i){
emlak <- read_html(sprintf(url_base,i))
fiyat <-emlak%>%html_nodes("#properties .price")%>%html_text()
alan <-emlak%>%html_nodes(".glyphicons-vector-path-square+ .detail-value")%>%html_text()
ilanno <-emlak%>%html_nodes(".fa-hashtag+ .detail-value")%>%html_text()
bolge <-emlak%>%html_nodes("#properties figure")%>%html_text()

data.frame(fiyat,alan,ilanno,bolge,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

}) -> emlak_table3

Is there any way to define dynamic iterator other than "%"? I would like to use same procuedure to scrape website and download pages data

Comment: To insert a literal `%` in `sprintf`, use `%%`. I.e. `sprintf('Your rate: %.1f%%', 31.4)`.

Comment: I couldn't get it. A bit more explanation based on the code provided can be very helpful

Comment: Every place in your string where you need a literal '%', use two. Every place where you need to insert a value, use one.

Comment: Thank you! it worked like a charm

Comment: @mrgumble can you add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

To insert a literal `%` in `sprintf`, use `%%`. I.e. `sprintf('Your rate: %.1f%%', 31.4)`.

Thus, every place in your string where you need a literal '%', use two. Every place where you need to insert a value, use one.